# PHP data update not successful if checkbox not click

Tags: php

I don't know what is wrong with my code below.

When I try to:

1. Update data if checkbox checked or unchecked then data will updated on database
2. Update data only Department Name, the data is not update on table.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="sub-modal-header">
    <div class="label">Department ID</div>

    <div class="input"><input type="text" id="departmentIDInput" readonly/></div>
</div>

<div class="sub-modal-header">
    <div class="label">Department Name</div>

    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="departmentNameInput" name="departmentNameInput" maxlength="30"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sub-modal-header">
    <div class="label">Active</div>

    <div class="input">
        <input type="hidden" name="departmentActiveVal" class="departmentActiveVal" id="departmentActiveVal"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="departmentActive" id="departmentActive"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
$('#btnUpdate').on('click', function()
{
     var departmentIDInput = $("#departmentIDInput").val();
     var departmentNameInput = $("#departmentNameInput").val();
     var departmentActiveVal = $("#departmentActiveVal").val();

     if((departmentNameInput.length == ""))
     {
        if(departmentNameInput == "")
        {
            $("#departmentNameInput").focus();
        }
     }
     else
    {
        if((departmentNameInput.length >= 2))
        {
            $('#departmentNameInput, #departmentActive').attr('readonly', true);

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "updateDepartment.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:
                {
                    departmentIDInput: $("#departmentIDInput").val(),
                    departmentNameInput: $("#departmentNameInput").val(),
                    departmentActive: $("#departmentActive").val(),
                    departmentActiveVal: $("#departmentActiveVal").val()
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (jsonStr)
                {

                }
            });

            $('#departmentNameInput, #departmentActive').attr('readonly', false);
        }
    }
```

PHP

```
if(isSet($_POST['departmentNameInput']) && isSet($_POST['departmentActiveVal']) && isSet($_POST['departmentIDInput']))
{
    $departmentIDInput = $_POST['departmentIDInput'];
    $departmentNameInput = $_POST['departmentNameInput'];
    $departmentActiveVal = $_POST['departmentActiveVal'];

    $updateDepartment = oci_parse($c1, "UPDATE WA_GA_TBL_DEPARTMENTS SET ACTIVE = '$departmentActiveVal', DEPARTMENTNAME = '$departmentNameInput' WHERE DEPARTMENTID = '$departmentIDInput'");
    oci_execute($updateDepartment);

$getResult = "updateSuccessfully";

$data = array(
            "departmentNameInput"     => $departmentNameInput,
            "departmentActiveVal"     => $departmentActiveVal,
            "result" => $getResult
        );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

What is wrong in that code?

Comment: Checkboxes are only sent to the PHP script from the Page if they are checked. Thats you problem

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly any trick for it?

Comment: Yea use `if (isset($checkboxname)) { //its checked} else { //its not checked}`

Comment: Or `$ValueToDB = isset($checkboxname) ? 1 : 0;` or whatever values are appropriate for the ON and OFF states